# Linq query with method syntax needed for two lists with type List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-method-syntax

```
var fullMessagesList = new List<string>(){
"This is Apple",
"This is mango",
"This is a Lemon",
"This is a Orange"
};

var partialMessagesList = new List<string>(){
"Apple",
"mango",
};
```

I need a linq query with method syntax with returns "This is a Lemon",
"This is a Orange" from fullMessagesList. I need to check for contains() for each text in another list.

I have written it using old school foreach loops but need to figure it with linq using method syntax.

```
var unknownFruites = new List<string>();
foreach (var message in fullMessagesList)
{
   var flag = 1;
   foreach (var partialmessage in partialMessagesList)
   {
      if (message.Contains(partialmessage))
      {
        flag = 0;
        break;
      } 
   }

   if (flag == 1)
   {
      unknownFruites.Add(message);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you return "This is a Orange" when the partial list doesn't contain "Orange"?

Comment: What is your attempt at LINQ? What are you having trouble with? `Where` and `Any` will be helpful.

Comment: `fullMessagesList.Where(s => partialMessagesList.Any(ps => s.Contains(ps))).ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var unknownFruites = fullMessagesList.Where(
    message => !partialMessagesList.Any(
        p => message.IndexOf(p, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
    )
);
```

The English interpretation of this code would be "select all messages where the message doesn't contain any string in the partial messages list."

Comment: is there any way to check contains() by ignoring case in the above query?

Comment: @MudassirHussain Yes, see my updated answer.  Note that you may want to use `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` instead. It depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore case:

```
var unknownFruites = fullMessagesList.Where(
    message => !partialMessagesList.Any(p => string.Compare(p, message, true) == 0)
);
```